# IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4: Enabling Tomcat access logs

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

How do I enable logging of access logs in IntelliJ?

I know that to enable it, this snippet needs to be added to server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

However, I can't add it to %SYSTEM%/tomcat/project/conf/server.xml because it gets overridden on startup.

I've also looked here: [image: IntelliJ log settings], which looks promising. The log files don't actually get written, so I don't see how that could be an acceptable "Log file location".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer given from filing a ticket with Jetbrains:

If you use Tomcat 7 entry for access log should already be present.

So for Tomcat 7 you need

1. to ensure that entry

   ```
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
     prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
     pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   ```

   is present in your server.xml file (the one in the Tomcat 7 installation directory).
2. Go to "Run\Debug configurations" window, open "Logs" tab and add new log alias like "Access Log" to with log file location `<CATALINA_BASE>\logs\localhost_access_log.*` (replacing  to your actual value e.g. `"C:/$USER_DIR/.IntellijIdea12/system/tomcat/<project>/"` and it makes sense to use wildcards)
3. Save run configuration and start it to see the `Access Log` tab

For Tomcat 6 the one below is recommended:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
  prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use Windows search hiden dirrectory `C:/$USER_DIR/.IntellijIdea12/system/tomcat/`

Comment: Nothing gets populated in that log directory. It is also the "%SYSTEM%" I am referring to in the question.